# Validation (CSS 2.1): 'behavior' is not a known CSS property name

Tags: css, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer-6, behavior, xhtml-1.1

I am using the [whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html) script to mimic the :hover selector in IE6. The suggested use is to attach it to the body element as an IE6 behavior. but all my pages use XHTML 1.1, so CSS validation in VS2008 fails when I try to publish my site.

Are there good ways to fix this?

Thanks!
konstantin

relevant markup:

```
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        behavior: url("../js/csshover3.htc");
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put

```
body
    {
        behavior: url("../js/csshover3.htc");
    }
```

in a external css

```
    <!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css">
    <![endif]-->
```

Edit:

or you can disable css errors

http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2008/03/17/quicktip-turn-off-css-validation-errors.aspx

Comment: thanks. but it does not help. visual studio can read css files too :)